# JavaFX View: Is there a difference between add and setConstraints?

Tags: java, javafx

Is there a difference between add() or setConstraints and so yes is a what is, Preference or really a big difference?

```
public class example extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Example");
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();

        Label label = new Label("Example A");
        Label label2 = new Label("Example B");

        grid.add(label, 0,0);

        GridPane.setConstraints(label2, 1, 0);
        grid.getChildren().add(label2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300,200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Implementation of the two methods in `GridPane` class:

```java
/**
 * Adds a child to the gridpane at the specified column,row position.
 * This convenience method will set the gridpane column and row constraints
 * on the child.
 * @param child the node being added to the gridpane
 * @param columnIndex the column index position for the child within the gridpane, counting from 0
 * @param rowIndex the row index position for the child within the gridpane, counting from 0
 */
public void add(Node child, int columnIndex, int rowIndex) {
    setConstraints(child, columnIndex, rowIndex);
    getChildren().add(child);
}
```

```java
/**
 * Sets the column,row indeces for the child when contained in a gridpane.
 * @param child the child node of a gridpane
 * @param columnIndex the column index position for the child
 * @param rowIndex the row index position for the child
 */
public static void setConstraints(Node child, int columnIndex, int rowIndex) {
    setRowIndex(child, rowIndex);
    setColumnIndex(child, columnIndex);
}
```

`add` method adds a child to the gridpane at the specified column, row position.
`setConstraints` Sets the column, row indeces for the child when contained in a gridpane.

**`setConstraints` doesn't add the child but specifies how it will be displayed inside the `GridPane`.**

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

`add` adds a Node and sets its constraints while `setConstraints` only sets constraints for a `Node` that has been added to `GridPane` before.

## From the [JavaDocs of `GridPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html):

```
public void add(Node child,
                int columnIndex,
                int rowIndex)
```

> Adds a child to the gridpane at the specified column,row position. This convenience method will set the gridpane column and row constraints on the child.
>
> Parameters:
> **child - the node being added to the gridpane**
> columnIndex - the column index position for the child within the gridpane, counting from 0
> rowIndex - the row index position for the child within the gridpane, counting from 0

**That means the `Node` passed is getting added and will be aligned according to the given constraints.**

---

```
public static void setConstraints(Node child,
                                  int columnIndex,
                                  int rowIndex,
                                  int columnspan,
                                  int rowspan)
```

> Sets the column, row, column-span, and row-span value for the child when contained in a gridpane.
>
> Parameters:
> **child - the child node of a gridpane**
> columnIndex - the column index position for the child
> rowIndex - the row index position for the child
> columnspan - the number of columns the child should span
> rowspan - the number of rows the child should span

**While this means you set the constraints of a `Node` that is already a child of the `GridPane` or may be added to one later, but this method never adds a `Node` itself.**

Comment: It's a bit nitpicky, but `setConstraints` works even if you apply it to a node that is added to the `children` list of a `GridPane` later. The javadoc is a bit ambiguous there. It seems like that sentence should be interpreted as "Sets the constraints used during the time the node is a child of a GridPane.", not "It sets the constaints, if the node is already added to a GridPane at the time the method is invoked and does nothing otherwise."

Comment: @fabian thanks, I didn't know that... But `setConstraints` never actually adds a `Node`, so that difference stays, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes and that's why you got the upvote in addition to the comment...

Answer (score 0):

I think you mix things up here?
setConstraints() sets the Layout to the childs constrains whereas add() simply adds a child object to a parent.